# Can't act with string's methods on a matched group

Tags: python, regex

I'm exercising a standard regexp:

```
Bill Gates → GATES, Bill
```

So I do:

```
In [21]: re.sub("([^ ]+) (.+)", r"\2".upper() + r", \1", "Bill Gates")
Out[21]: 'Gates, Bill'
```

Why it doesn't work? How does one applies string methods to a matched string?

Comment: You need to pass a function as the second argument to `re.sub`, which will take the match object as a parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are uppercasing (part of) the replacement *pattern*, not the actual replacement *result*.

The `r"\2".upper() + r", \1"` expression results in the value `"\\2, \\1"` *before* passing it to `re.sub()`.

To dynamically process match groups, you'll need to apply your changes in a function passed to `.sub()` instead of a replacement pattern:

```
def uppercase_last(match):
    return "{}, {}".format(match.group(2).upper(), match.group(1))

re.sub("([^ ]+) (.+)", uppercase_last, "Bill Gates")
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> def uppercase_last(match):
...     return "{}, {}".format(match.group(2).upper(), match.group(1))
... 
>>> re.sub("([^ ]+) (.+)", uppercase_last, "Bill Gates")
'GATES, Bill'
```

Alternatively, don't use regular expressions at all:

```
>>> name = 'Bill Gates'
>>> first, rest = name.split(None, 1)
>>> "{}, {}".format(rest.upper(), first)
```

Comment: Oh, I see -- so I have to get the result before uppercasing it. For this I have to pass it to a def.

Comment: @Adobe: Exactly. The function is passed the [match object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) and using the [`.group()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) we can get the various parts of the match and construct a result.